# Save speech to text in local using node js

Tags: node.js, speech-to-text, google-cloud-speech

I'm trying to replicate the code given at https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-speech/blob/master/samples/recognize.js. There is no error when I run it locally. But here I'm confused on where can I see the result that is created. Is there a way that I can write the result to a file?

Here is the code.

```
const record = require('node-record-lpcm16');

// Imports the Google Cloud client library
const speech = require('@google-cloud/speech');

// Creates a client
const client = new speech.SpeechClient();

/**
 * TODO(developer): Uncomment the following lines before running the sample.
 */
const encoding = 'LINEAR16';
const sampleRateHertz = 16000;
const languageCode = 'en-US';

const request = {
    config: {
        encoding: encoding,
        sampleRateHertz: sampleRateHertz,
        languageCode: languageCode,
    },
    interimResults: false, // If you want interim results, set this to true
};

// Create a recognize stream
const recognizeStream = client
    .streamingRecognize(request)
    .on('error', console.error)
    .on('data', data =>
        process.stdout.write(
            data.results[0] && data.results[0].alternatives[0] ?
            `Transcription: ${data.results[0].alternatives[0].transcript}\n` :
            `\n\nReached transcription time limit, press Ctrl+C\n`
        )
    );

// Start recording and send the microphone input to the Speech API
record
    .start({
        sampleRateHertz: sampleRateHertz,
        threshold: 0,
        // Other options, see https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-record-lpcm16#options
        verbose: false,
        recordProgram: 'sox', // Try also "arecord" or "sox"
        silence: '10.0',
    })
    .on('error', console.error)
    .pipe(recognizeStream);

console.log('Listening, press Ctrl+C to stop.');
```

This is very confusing :(. please let me know how can I achieve this.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It's in the "data". Please looking into [the code](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-speech/blob/master/samples/recognize.js) and see how the console logs the data.

Example:

```
client
.recognize(request)
.then(data => {
  const response = data[0];
  const transcription = response.results
    .map(result => result.alternatives[0].transcript)
    .join('\n');
  console.log(`Transcription: `, transcription);
})
```